# How to test DaoImpl methods using Junit and Mockito

Tags: spring, mockito, junit4, jdbctemplate

I am using spring with jdbcTemplate for my app and I want to test DaoImpl class. There is implementation for insertion, updation and retrieval operation

Dao class Method

```
//dummy class
public class PlayerDAOImpl implements PlayerDAO {

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


public Integer getPlayer(int playerId) {

    String sql = "SELECT ccount(1) FROM PLAYER WHERE 
     PLAYER_ID = ?";
     return  (jdbcTemplate. queryForObject("Query", new Object[]{playerId}, 
  Integer.class)!=0); //here only throws exception

}
//other methods
}
```

and for that I have written Test class which execute successfully for insertion and updation but while retrieving it is giving nullpointer exception.

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 class Test{
 @InjectMocks
  PlayerDAOImpl dao;
 @Mock
 JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Test
  public void retrieveResult(){

   Mockito.when(dao.getPlayer(int playerId)).thenReturn(false);

   //Assert Statement

  }}
```

I have googled/tried but not found solution which worked for me. So how to test that method or inject jdbcTemplate so that it will succeed.

Thanks for Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to mock the class under test (`PlayerDAOImpl`) instead of its dependency (`JdbcTemplate`).

Change you mock to something like:

```java
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()).thenReturn(COUNT);
```

Where `COUNT` is an `Integer`, and then write your assertions on the return value of `dao.getPlayer`.